# jQuery regex not showing updates

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I have a jQuery snippet I created and am having some issues with displaying the results dynamically. There is an image within each H2 tag. Below is my script of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<h2 id="test">This is a test <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" width="31" height="16" /></h2>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$('h2 img').each(function(){
var = test $(this).html();
$(this).html(test.replace(/<h2>(.*?)\s<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)(.*)\/><\/h2>/gi, '<h2>$1<img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" width="31" height="16" /></h2>'));
]);
```

It's supposed to move the image next to the word **test** (removes the extra space between the word test and img tag based on my regex).

Output is supposed to look like below (note: image tag is next to the word test):

```
<h2 id="test">This is a test<img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" width="31" height="16" /></h2>
```

I'm trying to accomplish this dynamically. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to remove the space after the word 'test' then you can amend the text node directly instead of hacking the HTML around as a string:

```js
let nodes = $('h2').contents().filter((i, node) => node.nodeType === 3);
Array.from(nodes).forEach(n => n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.trim());
```

```css
h2 img {
  width: 31px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a test <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" /></h2>
<h2>This is another test <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" /></h2>
<h2>foo bar <img class="test" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/new-xxl.png" alt="test" /></h2>
```

Better still, fix the problem at the source and don't rely on JS as a crutch to fix issues in your markup.

**-- Update --**

> one last thing can this be converted to a regular function instead of the arrow functions? –

```
let nodes = $('h2').contents().filter(function(i, node) {
  return node.nodeType === 3;
});
Array.from(nodes).forEach(function(n) {
  return n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.trim();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this based on the h2 tag instead of using the id in the h2? I have thousands of h2 tags with different ids

Comment: Sure, just use whatever selector you require. If you want it to work on all of them use a loop. I've edited the answer to show you how to do this

Comment: Thanks Rory. That did the trick. Really appreciate your assistance :)

Comment: one last thing can this be converted to a regular function instead of the arrow functions?

Comment: Sure, just updated the answer.

Comment: I see it now so going forward the arrow function is replaced with just (functions(.....). Cool deal. thanks again